# How to modify an enumeration created with DB-first Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-database-first

I followed the directions as detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19230633/3413608), and my enumeration was saved and can be utilized throughout the app. But in the case that I wanted to add additional options or change the names of existing options, how do I that?

I know I can do so by editing the EDMX file by hand in a text editor. I'd rather do it within Visual Studio in a fashion similar to how I generated the enumeration to begin with if it's possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the entity data model browser to update this. In your menu bar, navigate to `View -> Other Windows -> Entity Data Model Browser`. I think you need to have your edmx file open to see this option. That opens a model browser window and under the "Enum Types" folder you can double click your enum and update it.